# How to fix 'cannot read property call of undefined' error in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

In Developer Tools I get following error message in my Symfony project and I can't fix it.

I tried to edit my dev and public app.js and put out my Bootstrap there but I think this is the wrong way.

```
bootstrap:78 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
 at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
 at Object../assets/js/app.js (app.js:1)
 at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
 at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
 at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
 at app.js:1
```

app.js

```
require('../css/bootstrap.min.css');
//require('../css/admin.css');
require('../css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css');
require('../css/app.css');
var $ = require('jquery');
```

webpack/bootstrap:78

```
 modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, 
  __module.exports,__webpack_require__);
```

How can I figure it out?

Comment: The answer was: bootstrap was imported twice. After found and delete the 2nd import of bootstrap all was fine.